# Battery charging using a windmill?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, batteries

i want to charge 4*(12V/100AH battery) using a  3*( 12V/5AMP GENERATOR ) which is drawing its power from a windmill.
these battery have to heat 500 litre of water from 30 celcius to 50 celcius
how much time its going to take.
Windmill specifications ;- 3 blades gear ratio 1:18  with dynamo
air density 1.225kg/m3
wind avg velocity 3.5m/s
area of blades 10 m2.

Comment: Please define your problem more clearly. You ask "how much time is it going to take" for what?  To charge the battery or to heat the water ?

Answer (score 1):

Total charge required by your batteries is $Q_b = 4 \times 100 A.h = 400 A.h$

Maximum current supplied by generator is $I_g = 3 \times 5 A = 15 A$

So the time taken to charge the batteries is $400/15 = 26.67 hrs$

Now to calculate the energy required to heat 500L ($m$=500kg) of water from 30°C to 50°C (ie: increase temp by $\Delta T=20K$), we can use:

$H = m \times c_w \times \Delta T$

where $c_w=4.181 kJ/kg.K$ is the specific heat of water.

So

$H = 500 \times 4.181 \times 20 = 41,810$ kJ of energy required to heat the water.

Converting, $3.6kJ = 1W.h$, we can say $H=41810/3.6=11.614kW.h$ of energy.

Now, the maximum energy storage capacity for your batteries is:

$E = 4\times 12 \times 100=4800Wh=4.8kW.h$

Which is only about 41% of the energy required to heat the water.

This means you will need to obtain the remainder of the energy directly from the wind turbine and use the battery only when there was not enough wind.

Calculating the (theoretical) kinetic energy from the wind which can be transferred as power to the turbine:

$P_w=\frac{1}{2}A\rho v^3$ [W]

where $A=10m^2$ is the area of the blades

$\rho=1.225kg/m^3$ is the density of the air

$v=3.5m/s$ is the average wind velocity

Which gives $P_w=0.5\times 10 \times 1.225 \times (3.5)^3=262.6W$

So even if all of this wind power was used to heat the water, it would take:

$Time=\frac{H}{P_w}=\frac{11,614}{262.6}=44.2 hrs$

Comment: Your power numbers are not consistent between the two. 4 x 12v x 100 A-hr is 4800 W-hr. That's 18 hours at 262 W, not 26.7.